# $animate.enter() is not working with custom directive

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-animate

having trouble with angular-animate 1.4.3... the leave animation for a directive works fine, but the enter animation does not; from what I can see, the classes `ng-enter` and `ng-enter-active` are not being applied to the element. Why is this? [Here's a plunkr of it](http://plnkr.co/edit/hYCxuAriBg2vA2J5BBGm?p=preview)

script.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  // ---------------Module----------------

  angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])
    .run(['fooService', function(fooService) {
      fooService.foo('Hello World!');
    }]);

  // --------------Service----------------

  function fooService($rootScope, $compile, $animate, $timeout) {

    function createDirective(message) {
      var newFoo = {
        scope: $rootScope.$new()
      };

      var target = angular.element(document.querySelector('#bar'));
      var elem = angular.element(document.createElement('foo'));

      newFoo.scope.message = message;

      newFoo.elem = $compile(elem)(newFoo.scope);

      $animate.enter(newFoo.elem, target).then(function() {
        $timeout(function() {
          removeDirective(newFoo);
        }, 3000);
      });
    }

    function removeDirective(foo) {
      $animate.leave(foo.elem).then(function() {
        foo.scope.$destroy();
      });
    }


    function foo(message, overrides) {
      return createDirective(message);
    }

    return {
      foo: foo
    };
  }

  fooService.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$compile', '$animate', '$timeout'];

  angular.module('app')
    .factory('fooService', fooService);

  // -------------Directive---------------

  function fooDirective() {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      replace: true,
      templateUrl: 'foo.html',
      link: function(scope) {
      }
    }
  }

  angular.module('app')
    .directive('foo', fooDirective);

}());
```

foo.html

```
<div class="alert alert-success">
  {{message}}
</div>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.3.1" data-semver="3.3.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@~1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-animate@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="bar"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

style.css

```
.ng-leave, .ng-enter {
  transition: all 1s ease-out;
}

.ng-enter.ng-enter-active, .ng-leave {
  opacity: 1;
}

.ng-enter, .ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Appreciate any help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular doesn't link the directives on compilation. You can read a little about this [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2603-directive-controller-and-link-timing-in-angularjs.htm).

The implications for this case result in linking *after* `$animate.enter()`. You can wrap this call into a timeout but this is not a sustainable solution since this time varies dependent on how busy browser is and whether it's first time the directive is linked for this app. So I only see an approach based on promises. Due to the scope injection that is already in place for the custom directive, the latter can resolve the promise provided from the `fooService`

```
  newFoo.scope.deferred = $q.defer();
  newFoo.scope.deferred.promise.then(function(){
    console.log('$animate.enter');
    $animate.enter(newFoo.elem, target).then(function() {
      console.log('$animate.entered');
      $timeout(function() {
        removeDirective(newFoo);
      }, 3000);
    });
  });
```

And in directive the promise should be resolved on link

```
  link: function(scope) {
    console.log('foo.link');
    scope.deferred.resolve();
  }
```

[Updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3IT1Mq1uMnNV045F4Byn?p=preview)

Comment: Ah alright, I will read the article in greater detail but I kinda understand... thanks a lot! this really helps